# Can I set up KiTTY to send F7 press instead of bringing up Print dialogue when F7 button is pressed?

Tags: ssh, putty, utf-8, kitty

Can I set up KiTTY to send <kbd>F7</kbd> press instead of bringing up Print dialogue when I press <kbd>F7</kbd>?

I make intense use of *Midnight Commander* and its editor, which both rely on <kbd>F7</kbd> (to create a directory and to search through text) and I never actually print from a terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to http://www.9bis.net/kitty/index.php?action=forum&id=0144 just change print={F7} in the [Shortcuts] section of your config file to something else, e.g. print={SHIFT}{F7}.

Comment: I used to have print={SHIFT}{F7} and printall={F7} there. I've just removed both (as I NEVER print), but it didn't help. Printing still pops up on F7 :-(

Comment: I've replaced F7 with F12 then and this has solved the problem practically (so, I accept the answer as correct), but I'd prefer to remove this at all if possible.

Comment: I gave a few things a shot, and found that creating kitty.ini, in the location of kitty.exe, with the text:
`[KiTTY]
shortcuts=no`
...will also disable F7's action of printing.

Comment: If you're looking for `kitty.ini` on Windows, I found mine in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\KiTTY\`.

Comment: To disable a shortcut I assign an empty value to it, `printall=`.

Comment: Current documentation location: http://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/MenuShortcuts.md

Answer (score 1):

Right click / Shortcuts toggle - off will turn off shortcuts alltogether.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works something like this:

1. Change to empty
   print=
   printall=
   But Kitty continues to use previous values ( {SHIFT}{F7} ,{F7} )
2. Change to something else, for example:
   print={}
   printall={}
3. Run Kitty and it works! F7 in mc shows "Create a new Directory" dialog